# I have set 2checkout to sandbox mode, doing a test payment but instead of "vendor_order_id" I am getting "merchant_order_id" in the response.

Tags: 2checkout

"middle_initial":"",
"sid":"901337742",
"fixed":"Y",
"cart_weight":"0",
"submit":"Pay Now",
"key":"05C51931DE8007C210DC74EEF7B9E9AF",
"state":"ID",
"last_name":"",
"email":"snehal@mailinator.com",
"city":"PUNE",
"street_address":"abcd",
"cart_order_id":"21",
"merchant_order_id":"21",
"order_number":"9093733629543",
"country":"IND",
"ip_country":"India",
"cart_id":"21",
"currency_code":"USD",
"lang":"en",
"demo":"",
"pay_method":"CC",
"invoice_id":"9093733629552",
"cart_tangible":"N",
"phone":" ",
"total":"25.00",
"credit_card_processed":"Y",
"zip":"411038",
"street_address2":"",
"x_receipt_link_url":"",
"first_name":"snehal",
"card_holder_name":"snehal"

Answer (score 0):

vendor_order_id is only returned when using https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/api/sales/detail-sale  - Otherwise merchant_order_id(Optional) is the parameter being used. In the end, these parameters do share the same value, they're just named slightly different depending on where you're getting the data from.